# makeEwsRequestAsync fails to work in Outlook 2016 for Windows

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I was trying to develop a sample Outlook add-in with the Office JS API.

The add-in has the following setup:

- Exchange 2016
- Read/Write Mailbox permissions
- OAuthAuthentication set to true on the Client Access Server EWS directory

With this, I'm able to make makeEwsRequestAsync calls to EWS from Outlook Web Access.

However, with Outlook 2016 for Windows, the requests to EWS fail.
Using Fiddler, I see some HTTPS 401 Unauthorized responses:

> POST https://ad12exch16.latveria.lab.proofpoint.com/EWS/exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1

The getUserIdentityTokenAsync method does work though.
Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: What specific version number of Outlook 2016 were you on?
Also what specific version of Exchange 2016. There is a known issue with this error happening when the Internal and External EWS URLs are different. 

If you are on-prem exchange, you can check the EWS Urls by running "Get-WebServicesVirtualDirectory | fl" Then looking at the Internal/External URLs.

Comment: @bdeo it is quite old post, but I encountered the same error. Did solve it somehow? Can provide info about it? Thx.

Comment: @thadam unfortunately, I did not look at this issue further. Perhaps Tim Wan's comment above can provide a hint, looks like there is a known issue with some exchange versions.